# BlueZ 5 - Connecting to a Bluetooth LE heart rate watch

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm pretty much new to using BlueZ 5 and I've been experimenting with a Bluetooth LE heart rate watch. I would really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

When I run the "test-heartrate" test, I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-heartrate", line 88, in <module>
    properties = dev_prop.GetAll(HEARTRATE_INTERFACE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line
651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs:
No such interface 'org.bluez.HeartRate1'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here're some relevant information

BlueZ version installed: 5.24

For installation, I followed the steps listed in: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/bluez.html (with one addition: I added `--enable-experimental` during configuration)

It seems I'm facing the same issue as described at:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.bluez.kernel/47931
I've followed the suggestion provided as well as tried passing -E to
bluetoothd while running it but to no avail.

I can successfully run:

- test-discovery : To discover devices, including the heart-rate watch
- test-device connect : To connect to this device

But the one that is failing for me is test-heartrate

Even after connecting to the device, when I try to introspect:
 `dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply [obj_path] org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect`, I don't see the
`org.bluez.HeartRate1` interface showing up, with its appropriate methods.

I can post the entire introspection data, along with the device properties that I get, if that helps.

Would really appreciate any helpful pointer in this regard. Thanks!!